# JavaScript continuously running in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I cannot figure out why my code continues to run even though it appears to have completely loaded the proper HTML. This problem only appears in Firefox (using ver. 3.5.3) and not in IE. This is just a simple script to display a multiplication table with a few decorative effects mixed in.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Multiplication Table</title>
    <script>
      function drawTable(){
        var rb = document.configForm.rowBegin.value - 1;
        var re = document.configForm.rowEnd.value;
        var cb = document.configForm.colBegin.value - 1;
        var ce = document.configForm.colEnd.value;
        document.write("Perfect squares are highlighted in red.<p>");
        document.write("<table border=\"1\">");
        for(i = rb; i <= re; i++){
          document.write("<tr>");
          for(j = cb; j <= ce; j++){
            if(i == rb && j == cb){
            // ignore top left corner
              document.write("<td bgcolor=\"#ffffff\"></td>");
            }
            else if(i == rb){
            // to display the column headers
              if(j % 2 == 0)
                document.write("<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#99d9e0\">" + j + "</td>");
              else
                document.write("<td align=\"center\">" + j + "</td>");
            }
            else if(j == cb){
            // to display the row headers
              if(j % 2 == 0)
                document.write("<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#99d9e0\">" + i + "</td>");
              else
                document.write("<td align=\"center\">" + i + "</td>");
            }
            else{
            // writes the solutions to the table
              if(i == j || Math.sqrt(i*j) % 1 == 0)
              // highlight the perfect squares
                document.write("<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#ff8080\">" + i * j + "</td>");
              else if(j % 2 == 0)
                document.write("<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#99d9e0\">" + i * j + "</td>");
              else
                document.write("<td align=\"center\">" + i * j + "</td>");
            }
          }
          document.write("</tr>");
        }
        document.write("</table>");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Multiplication Table</h2>
    <form name="configForm">
      Row Range:</br>
        Begin&nbsp;<input type="text" name="rowBegin" size="5">
        End&nbsp;<input type="text" name="rowEnd" size="5">
      <p>
      Column Range:</br>
        Begin&nbsp;<input type="text" name="colBegin" size="5">
        End&nbsp;<input type="text" name="colEnd" size="5">
      <p>
      <input type="Submit" value="Make Table" onclick="return drawTable()">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `document.close();` to the end of the function. It appears that Firefox doesn't realize that you're done writing.

Answer (score 1):

If you use document.write() you need to use document.close(); to tell the browser you are done.

Using something like alert(); can also stop the spinner from spinning but that isn't likely what you want.